# Spring MVC: How to unit test Model's attribute from a controller method that returns String?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

For example,

```
package com.spring.app;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(final Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "SUCCESS");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

I want to test `model`'s attribute and its value from `home()` using JUnit. I can change return type to `ModelAndView` to make it possible, but I'd like to use `String` because it is simpler. It's not must though.

Is there anyway to check `model` without changing `home()`'s return type? Or it can't be helped?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Spring MVC Test](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework):

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(model().attribute("msg", equalTo("SUCCESS"))) //or your condition
```

And [here](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-normal-controllers/) is fully illustrated example

Comment: Not that it is wrong, but this is an integration and not an unit test.

Comment: what is the purpose to unit test map? cause model is almost a map

Comment: Assume the controller contains view related logic and you want to cover that logic with unit tests. But it might be that he wants an integration test and was asking for the wrong thing. Don't see my comment as your incorrect or something like this.

Comment: @mh-dev i just think that i understood question in incorrect way and my answer is not relevant, just trying to image this situation with controller unit test. so you have to call controller method directly and pass this model as  argument

Comment: I have an error,  "The method model() is undefined for the type IndexControllerTest". In my controller I have model.addObject

Comment: This doesn't work when the `@Controller` method returns `void` despite using `Model` as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mockito for that.

Example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) 
public HomeControllerTest {

    private HomeController homeController;
    @Mock
    private Model model;

    @Before
    public void before(){
        homeController = new HomeController();
    }

    public void testSomething(){
        String returnValue = homeController.home(model);
        verify(model, times(1)).addAttribute("msg", "SUCCESS");
        assertEquals("hello", returnValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's checking if `addAttribute("msg", "SUCCESS")` is called, but not actually checking `model`. Can it be changed into something like this? `Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); map.put("msg", "SUCCESS"); assertThat(model.asMap(), is(map));`

Comment: Model itself is an interface, but you can do a simple implementation that does what you need and us this one instead of the mocked Model.