# Spring test: how to 'pass' model into controller post method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing, integration-testing

I'm working in Spring Boot and am trying to write an integration test for a controller that looks like this:

```
public String pagerequestSubmit(@ModelAttribute Pagerequest pagerequest, Model model) {
...
 }
```

Now I'm trying to write an integration test for this controller like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=PageAnalyzerInSpringApplication.class)
public class PagerequestControllerIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
PagerequestController pagerequestController;

@Test
public void testHappyPath() {


    Pagerequest mockPageRequest = new Pagerequest();
    mockPageRequest.setUrl("https://www.somedomain.com/");
    ....

    String outcome = pagerequestController.pagerequestSubmit(mockPageRequest);

    assertThat(outcome, is(equalTo("result")));

}
```

I don't have any problem doing the 'mock pagerequest' and passing it into the post method, so I got that far, but the above test does not work because I get:

"The method pagerequestSubmit(Pagerequest, Model) in the type PagerequestController is not applicable for the arguments (Pagerequest)"

Which makes sense because I'm not passing in any argument of the type Model
and I'm completely stuck on how to do that.

I've tried to instantiate a Model, which doesn't work, creating a fake Model, which also didn't work, and passing in a Model variable that was null, which at least gets the test running, but then throws a null pointer exception when the model in used in the controller.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pagerequestSubmit(@ModelAttribute Pagerequest pagerequest, Model model)`  accepts two arguments one is pagerequest and other is model but in your test you are passing only pagerequest .You need to pass model object as well.This is just wrong method signature in your test class .
Create a mock of model object and paste that in your code as

```
 @Mock
    private Model model;

 String outcome = pagerequestController.pagerequestSubmit(mockPageRequest,model);
 assertThat(outcome, is(equalTo("result")));
```

Comment: Also you can use spring mv c test  Refer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120991/spring-mvc-how-to-unit-test-models-attribute-from-a-controller-method-that-ret